# Restangular - _.contains() is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash, restangular

If you have recently updated restangular through bower it will have installed the latest lodash - the new 4.0. However this is a problem as restangular/angular now throws the error - "_.contains() is not a function."

How do you solve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is very simple - you need to tell restangular to use a lower version than the newest lodash - 3.10.0

Through bower.json

```
 "lodash": "~3.10.0"
```

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/1298

Comment: Removed 17 aliases
_.all, _.any, _.backflow, _.callback, _.collect, _.compose, _.contains, _.detect, _.foldl, _.foldr, _.include, _.inject, _.methods, _.object, _.#run, _.select, & _.unique

Answer (score 7):

Couldn't you put this in app.js

```
// If Restangular ever updates to lodash 4.0 remove this.
_.contains = _.includes
```

Comment: you could really just do this 

    _.contains =  _.includes;

check out lodash.js and mapping.js in lodash. I think that is essentiall what they are doing here. 

lodash.js
    lodash.each = forEach;

mapping.js
    'forEach': ['each']

I'd just rather monkeypatch until it's fixed rather than downgrade my everything for one method.

Comment: Just replace all calls for `_.contains` with `_.includes`

Answer (score 4):

If you have not specified the entry for `lodash` explicitly and this gets installs as a dependency of `restangular`, you can uninstall both of them and reinstall `lodash (3.10.1)` to fix the issue.

```
bower uninstall restangular
bower uninstall lodash
bower install --save lodash#3.10.1
bower install --save restangular
```

This way you would not need an entry into the `bower.json` file.

Source: https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/1294