# Getting .Fatal error: grunt.util._.contains is not a function while saving code after grunt debug

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, gruntjs

I have two version of grunt one global and one local.
grunt-cli v1.2.0
grunt v1.0.1
I want to uninstall v1.0.1.
When running grunt debug command it running successfully but while saving code am getting this fatal error:grunt.util._.contains is not a function.

**bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "__",
  "version": "__",
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.5",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.18",
    "angular-mocks": "^1.5.5",
    "angular-bootstrap": "^1.3.2",
    "ngstorage": "^0.3.10",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "angular-resource": "^1.2.28",
    "ng-file-upload-shim": "^12.0.4",
    "ng-file-upload": "^12.0.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angularjs-slider": "^5.4.1"
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
    {
  "author": "....",
  "name": "....",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "homepage": ".....",
  "licenses": {
    "type": "MIT",
    "url": "...."
  },
  "bugs": "....",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "..."
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-bump": "0.0.6",
    "grunt-coffeelint": "~0.0.10",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.4.3",
    "grunt-contrib-less": "~0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.2.7",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.4.4",
    "grunt-conventional-changelog": "^0.1.2",
    "grunt-html2js": "^0.1.9",
    "grunt-karma": "^0.8.2",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^0.8.0",
    "karma": "^0.12.9",
    "karma-coffee-preprocessor": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.1.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922682/restangular-contains-is-not-a-function

Comment: I tried with this, getting same error. NO change

Comment: you need to provide some more info like some code, or steps you took already to try fix your problem. More info you provide, will help us understand your problem

Comment: Added bower.json and package.json.

Answer (score 3):

It is due to incompatible grunt version, so I followed the below commands:
I Uninstalled Grunt:

```
>npm uninstall -g grunt
```

I Installed Grunt-cli:

```
>npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Then i checked the version:

```
>grunt --version
```

> grunt-cli v1.2.0
>   grunt v1.0.1

I got the above response, but i needed grunt v0.4.5

Then i installed the needed grunt version:

```
npm install grunt@0.4.5 --save-dev
```

Now I don't get the above specified error.